# Insert XML File Data into Existing Table

Tags: sql-server, xml

I'm trying to insert contents of an XML file into an existing table.  So far I only have the below:

```
DECLARE @NewCustomers XML;
SET @NewCustomers = '
<NewCustomers>

<Customer LastName="Chan" FirstName="Isabella" Password="" 
EmailAddress="izzychan@yahoo.com"/>

<Customer LastName="Prine" FirstName="John" Password="" 
EmailAddress="johnprine@gmail.com"/>

<Customer LastName="Kitchen" FirstName="Kathy" Password="" 
EmailAddress="kathykitchen@sbcglobal.net"/>

</NewCustomers>
'
;

INSERT INTO Customers (EmailAddress, Password, FirstName, LastName)
Values(
@NewCustomers
)
GO
```

But I get an error "There are more columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement."

And Completely stumped here anything can help Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XML will not parse itself.

**Example**

```
INSERT INTO Customers (EmailAddress, Password, FirstName, LastName)
Select EMailAddress = x.v.value('@EmailAddress','VARCHAR(150)')
      ,Password     = x.v.value('@Password','VARCHAR(150)')
      ,FirstName    = x.v.value('@FirstName','VARCHAR(150)')
      ,LastName     = x.v.value('@LastName','VARCHAR(150)')
 From  @NewCustomers.nodes('NewCustomers/Customer') x(v)
```

**The Select will produce the following**

```
EMailAddress                    Password    FirstName   LastName
izzychan@yahoo.com                          Isabella    Chan
johnprine@gmail.com                         John        Prine
kathykitchen@sbcglobal.net                  Kathy       Kitchen
```

Comment: Thank you so much that worked well for me!  I could not for the life of me get that haha

Comment: @Ryan Happy to help.  We all get stuck from time to time  :)